# Swift 4 Decodable and newlines \n

Tags: json, swift

The iTunes search API returns JSON that sometimes contains newlines (\n).

This makes decoding fail.

You can see an example here:

curl "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ruismaker&entity=software&media=software&limit=1"

Here's my stripped-down (there is much more in the actual response) domain struct:

```
public struct iTunesSoftware: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case iTunesDescription = "description"
    }

    public var iTunesDescription: String?
}
```

Here is some test code:

```
let jstring = """
{
"description": "This App requires \n iPad 4, Mini 2",
}
"""
// try it with and without the newline to see the problem
let encoded = String(jstring.filter { !" \n\t\r".contains($0) })
let encodedData = encoded.data(using: .utf8)!
//let encodedData = jstring.data(using: .utf8)!
```

And then decode:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()    
do {
        let app = try decoder.decode(iTunesSoftware.self, from: encodedData)
        print(app)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

But in practice, you get back a Data object from a call to a REST service.

```
 let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {
                (data, _, err) -> Void in

                 // I have a Data object, not a String here.
                 // I can do this:
                 if let s = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                      filter it, turn it back into a Data object, then decode
                      let encoded = String(s.filter { !" \n\t\r".contains($0) })
                      let encodedData = encoded.data(using: .utf8)
                      var encodedData: Data?
                      if let s = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) {
                          // filter it, turn it back into a Data object, then decode
                          let encoded = String(s.filter { !" \n\t\r".contains($0) })
                          encodedData = encoded.data(using: .utf8)
                      }
                      guard let theData = encodedData else {
                         return
                      }

                      // and then later:
                      let app = try decoder.decode(iTunesSoftware.self, from: theData)
```

So, my question is: Really? This is such a common use case - and it's coming from an Apple REST Service. You would think the decoder would allow you to set something to ignore control characters.

JSONDecoder has various strategy properties such as this:

```
open var dataDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DataDecodingStrategy
```

Are you supposed to create a custom KeyedDecodingContainer to override decode for String?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Actually `JSONDecoder` should decode strings containing newline and whitespace characters correctly. The backslash in the literal string of the example must be escaped `"description": "This App requires \\n iPad 4, Mini 2"`

Comment: According to http://json.org, control characters are not valid in JSON strings, and a newline character must be escaped as `\n` (which is `\\n` in a Swift string literal). – Can you share an URL which returns such a problematic response?

Comment: The iTunes search API returns it. Here's an example where you can see it. Look at description.   curl "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ruismaker&entity=software&media=software&limit=1"

Comment: I cannot see a newline inside strings in that response, only `\n` (i.e. backslash character followed by "n").

Comment: The \n is what is making the decoder barf.

Comment: @GeneDeLisa: Your above test code creates a string containing a newline character (U+000A). The response of that iTunes API does *not* contain newline characters inside strings, only backslash-n sequences, i.e. *escaped* newline characters. Your above example is not the same what the iTunes API returns. – Pasting the iTunes response into https://jsonlint.com reports no errors. Your problem must be something different.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

One of the lessons I've learned and relearned in 36 years of programming is "it's not where you think it is". I thought it was a weird Decodable problem. So, I went from my QuickSpec to a playground to isolate it. Not a bad thing, but it was 5am and I had only one espresso at that time.

tl;dr the problem was my testing session mock which read the json from a file. I usually do both tests - actual networking calls and from a file. I mistakenly copied a bit of junk into the file. D'Oh!

Thank you for your responses. My guess is that your day is starting better than mine :)